# Merge sort: Why does my merge method only add one number to the queue?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, queue, mergesort

Here is my code:

```
void mergeHelper(Queue<T> input1, Queue<T> input2, Queue<T> output) {
            // TODO 4
            if(!input1.isEmpty())
            {
                T ip1 = input1.dequeue();
                if(!input2.isEmpty())
                {
                    T ip2 = input2.dequeue();
                    if(ip1.compareTo(ip2)<=0)
                        output.enqueue(ip1);
                    else
                        output.enqueue(ip2);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.enqueue(ip1);
                }
                mergeHelper(input1, input2, output);
            }
            else if(!input2.isEmpty())
            {
                T ip2 = input2.dequeue();
                if(!input1.isEmpty())
                {
                    T ip1 = input1.dequeue();
                    if(ip1.compareTo(ip2)<=0)
                        output.enqueue(ip1);
                    else
                        output.enqueue(ip2);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.enqueue(ip2);
                }
                mergeHelper(input1, input2, output);
            }

    }
```

Here is a temporary driver:

```
public class MergeDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MergeSorter<Integer> ms = new MergeSorter<>();
        Queue<Integer> one = new Queue<>();
        Queue<Integer> two = new Queue<>();
        one.enqueue(new Integer(2));
        two.enqueue(new Integer(1));
        Queue<Integer> res = ms.merge(one, two);
        System.out.println("The size of res is: "+ res.size());
        System.out.println("The value stored is: ");
        while(!res.isEmpty())
            System.out.println((int)res.dequeue());
    }

}
```

Only 1 is added to the output queue and the rest is not.

The resulting queue size is always one and the only the smallest element is added to the queue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any special purpose of using `Queue`? You can perform merge sort with simple arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is incorrect because it dequeues both items for comparison, but adds only one of them back to the output.

You can fix this by using [`peek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#peek()) method prior to dequeueing, comparing the results, and only then dequeueing the smaller of the two elements, and moving it into the output.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks! :)